# Не получается сверстать элемент с макета

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

Верстаю сайт, в макете осталась кнопка, которая вылазит при наведении на таблицу, но я не знаю как ее реализовать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
#faq {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 70px;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#faq div {
  width: 25%;
  margin-left: 6%;
  float: left;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background-color: #E8E8E8;
  border-bottom: 80px solid #E8E8E8;
}

#faq div img {
  width: 100%;
}

#faq .title {
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: #a3a0ad;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

#faq .heading {
  color: 7d7d7d;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#faq p {
  font-family: Comfortaa, sans-serif;
  color: #4a4a4a;
  font-size: 0.95em;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

#faq img {
  width: 50%;
}

#faq span {
  margin-left: 30px;
  font-family: Russo One, serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="faq">
  <div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x500">
    <span class="heading">Какие гарантии есть?</span>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur aperiam obcaecati aut!.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x500">
    <span class="heading">Как будет проходить поездка?</span>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi optio ullam aliquid.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x500">
    <span class="heading">Какие города в списке?</span>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut dolore non alias.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а что случилось, почему у вас не получается сделать? в чем возникли трудности?

Comment: просто не понимаю, как ее сделать, уже все перепробовал ничего не получается. Где-то минут 30 с ней сижу уже

Comment: а где кнопка в разметке? код в сниппете вообще не похож на картинку

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Такой вариант устроит?

```css
#faq {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  gap: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

#faq .card {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 350px;
  min-height: 250px;
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 400px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,.65);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#faq .card img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

#faq .card .info {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -50px;
}

#faq .card .info .text {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#faq .card .info .text h2 {
  
}

#faq .card .info .text p {
  
}

#faq .card .info .link {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #ff7b00;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px -3px rgba(0,0,0,.65) inset;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 130%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#faq .card:hover .info {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="faq">
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/qAHyYTN.png">
    <div class="info">
      <div class="text">
        <h2>Заголовок</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      </div>
      <a class="link" href="#">Кнопка</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/vVX2fwd.png">
    <div class="info">
      <div class="text">
        <h2>Заголовок</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      </div>
      <a class="link" href="#">Кнопка</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/K0JaqYY.png">
    <div class="info">
      <div class="text">
        <h2>Заголовок</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      </div>
      <a class="link" href="#">Кнопка</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: полезный ответ, просто и со вкусом, приятный дизайн

Comment: У меня только один вопрос.. Почему этот ответ столько "лайков" собрал? О.о